# Time-shifting property - Laplace transform of f(t) = $e^tH(t-3)$ where H is the heaviside function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of f(t) = $e^tH(t-3)$

If someone could talk me through this, that would be much appreciated!

Like I tried it but I kept getting F(s) = $e^{-3s}\frac{1}{s-1}$ which is incorrect :(

Thanks a million!

Comment: What is $\text{H}(t-3)$?

Comment: Heaviside function

Comment: So its a time-shift of 3.

Comment: $e^{-3s}$ should read $e^{3-3s}$.

Comment: yeah but why? like how do u get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $f(t) = e^3 e^{t-3} H(t-3)$ and look up the tables...